# Overlap of DNA in Python programming

Tags: python, overlap

The output should be the similarity length, in this case 15(length)

[image]

Can anyone helps me?

Comment: I suggest you read about the [LCS problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem). [Here's](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence#Python) a site with some basic implementation of that algorithm.

Comment: This isn't your homework, is it? Anyhow, the [Needleman–Wunsch algorithm] (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman–Wunsch_algorithm) may help here.